# legend is missing when I used add_subplot function

Tags: python, pandas

I plan to graph a data with tow subplot.
In the first subplot, it is including all stock price, moving average(window = 5),moving average( window = 8) and moving average( window = 13)

In the second subplot, it is just including RSI.

I initially obtain a serious of data that is the stock price (using date as index)
then, I define a function called ema to create a serious of data that is the moving average.

after that I also create a function called rsi to create a serious of data that is the rsi.

Then I try to define the following function called graph_with_indicator.
In this function, I firstly join all ema and the stock price together as a dataframe 
Then I create the rsi serious.

Next, i used add_subplot(211) to plot the first dataframe.
After that, I used add_subplot(212) to plot rsi.

actually it is successful, excluding the legend.
It can only produce the rsi legend, but not to the first graph.

Can anyone help me for this?

Is it because my first graph is a dataframe but the second one is just a serious, therefore, I can produce the legend of the second one?

And I got another question from it, Can I actually join all the data into one dataframe, then make the subplot separately. For instance, I got a five columns dataframe, then produce the first two columns into the first subplot and the last two columns into the second subplot?

Here is my code:

```
def graph_with_indicator(stock):
    #5,8,13
    df = pd.DataFrame(stock)
    name = str(df.columns[0])
    windows = [5,8,13]
    for window in windows:
        df_tmp = ema(stock,window)
        df = df.join(df_tmp)

    stock_rsi = rsi(stock,14) 


    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle(name, fontsize=20)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)

    ax1.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
    ax1.plot(df)
    ax2.plot(stock_rsi)
    ax1.legend(loc='upper left')
    ax2.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.subplots_adjust(left= 0.1, bottom= 0.1, right= 0.98, top= 0.9, wspace= 0, hspace= 0.1 )

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the legends to work, change these two lines

```
ax1.plot(df)
ax2.plot(stock_rsi)
```

to these:

```
ax1.plot(df, label="df")
ax2.plot(stock_rsi, label="stock_rsi")
```

The reason why is because Matplotlib's artist requires labels to draw legends.